# Trying to spoof an email address

Tags: python, email

I'm sure this has been asked, but I can't find anything to get mine to work.

I'm trying to send follow up emails to clients, but I want to spoof the email address so the from address is for my coworker. I read somewhere online that the from address in the header is simply a text field that can be edited, but I still cannot send the email.

```
import smtplib

email_to = '*****@gmail.com'
username = '*******@outlook.com'
password = '*********'
other_email = '*******@outlook.com'

mail = smtplib.SMTP('Outlook.com', 25)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(username,password)

header = ('To:' + email_to + '\n' +'From: ' + other_email + '\n'
          + 'Subject: Python Project Test\n')
message = (header +
           '\n\n This is a test message generated from a Python script. \n\n')

mail.sendmail(username, email_to, message)
mail.close()
print("Email sent successfully.")
```

I know this can be done, but can someone point me in the right direction?  Is there any way for me to disguise my name in the from field as that of the email that is supposed to get this?

===================================

Also, for the sake of completion, here is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\email outlook.py", line 16, in <module>
    mail.sendmail(username, email_to, message)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 887, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender')
```

I was hoping if there was a way to make the other_name an alias of the username.

Comment: What happens when you run that program?

Comment: Could show something like your error message or more detail about "I still cannot send the email"? Does the sendmail() works fine but the receiver didn't get the mail? Or it just doesn't work?

Comment: I know that you have to "Allow less secure apps" to send email from a gmail account like this. I presume you have to do something for sending from an outlook account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The *very* short version:** This isn't going to work.

---

Once upon a time, it was reasonably possible to do what you are asking to do.  In the old days, when the internet was small and spam did not exist, the receiving server would just trust you.  You could just connect to mail.example.com and say you were sending on behalf of someone@example.org, and example.com would just believe you.

But those days are over and done with.  Nowadays, SMTP servers are a lot less trusting.  So let's go through the problems with your approach:

1. You are trying to route your email through outlook.com.  outlook.com knows perfectly well that you are `username` and not `other_email`.  If you want to send email as `other_email`, you need to authenticate as `other_email`.
2. You could connect directly to gmail.com, claim to be outlook.com, and try to send the email that way.  But Gmail knows you're not outlook.com, because you're missing [these things](https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/).  So it will likely flag your message as spam, bounce it, or even* accept it and then discard it entirely.

You could fix (1) by changing your code, but because of (2), there's little point.

* I do not work on the Gmail team.  I am guessing how Gmail would respond to this based solely on public information about how modern email servers are typically configured.  YMMV.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was sending the email to Gmail just to test if it the code works.

Comment: Because this came up in a related question, perhaps emphasize that this is a common restriction for *consumer* email infrastructure. Once you have your own email server with a good reputation, all sorts of trickery from the dark 1990s become possible again.

Comment: @triplee: The way to get a "good reputation" in the first place is by *not* doing this sort of thing.  Eventually someone will notice and put your domain on a spam list, often with very little due process or advance warning.

Comment: @Kevin Sure; but it's all a game of statistics. A large operator can maintain a good reputation even if it has a few bad clients.