# Why does SendGrid allow me to send emails from any address?

Tags: python, smtp, sendgrid, smtp-auth

I have a local python file that I'm using to send emails through sendgrid's SMTP:

```
gmail_sender = "example@gmail.com"
server_username = "apikey"
server_password = prod.CONFIG['sendgrid_SMTP']

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.sendgrid.net', 465)
server.login(server_username, server_password)

email_information['From'] = gmail_sender

server.sendmail(email_information['From'], email_information['To'], 
    email_information.as_string())
```

I'm confused about who is sending the email. I replaced gmail_sender with multiple different emails, and without having to give the password to those emails, I could send an email through sendgrid's SMTP. In the from section of the email I sent, it says the email I put as the gmail_sender plus "via sendgrid.net." I can make it seem like anyone sent the email, isn't this a security concern?

Any guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think most email providers accept this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750465/trying-to-spoof-an-email-address

Comment: Thanks for the link; I feel like it shouldn't be possible, but I just did it...

Comment: @jamesfdearborn The linked question basically demonstrates a common restriction for *consumer* email infrastructure. Once you have your own email server with a good reputation, all sorts of trickery from the dark 1990s become possible again.

Comment: (... Or a contract with someone who is willing to rent you one, just to explicitly cover this case too.)

Comment: I am just getting started with sendgrid and the format for creating then sender generates an error, when I use my actual email address, that says the 'from email must be unique'. I can't find any documentation for it. I made up a new email address (on my domain) but I don't actually have a user with that name. It doesn't make any sense to me that this would be a requirement for using sendgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative is rather daunting. You would have to technically prove to them that every address you want to send from is actually yours.

Some services require you to prove that a *domain* is yours by giving you a unique cookie and telling you to publish it in the domain's DNS records. If you have control over the DNS for a domain, you have the control over the domain. But there is no similar mechanism for email - you could simply forge the sender on the email which is supposed to prove that you own the address.

Anyway, going through this ordeal for every domain you want to use is already a chore. Imagine what it would mean for clients who want to use dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of different sender addresses.

The Sendgrid terms of service have some general language about network abuse, which *probably* apply to using somebody else's email address. I could find nothing specific about address forgery in their ToS. Having a legal restriction in a contract (and enforcing it!) relieves them from the need to implement a technical restriction.

Comment: why would any company need to use more than one sender address?

Comment: Trust me, they do. Different campaigns, different departments, different mailing lists...